# Asign component variable with result of async method in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, methods, parameters

I'm trying to build an application and I don't want my component to have unnecessary code. There is a lot of logic that I would like to put in a service and then inject the service into my component.
Let say my component has a variable named 'result':

**my.component.ts**

```
    .....

    private result:number;
```

and my service has an async method:

**my.services.ts**

```
    ......
    ......

    getNumberFromApi(){
    callAsync().subscribe( data => {
        console.log('This is the data obtained..'+data);
    })
```

I would like to have the chance of passing a parameter to the method getNumberFromApi():

```
    getNumberFromAPI(destinationVar:number){
    callAsync().subscribe( data => {
        console.log('This is the data obtained..'+data);
        destinationVar=data;
    })
```

So that in my component I would be able to call the method of this service in this way:

**my.component.ts**

```
    .....

    private result:number;
    myServiceInstance.getNumberFromApi(result);
```

I understand this is  not possible (probably because the method's stack is already gone at the time the response arrives) but I don't find a way to do this or something similar. Can somebody recommend me an alternative? I would like to modify **from the service** variables of the component, even with async methods, *without* anything more than a method invocation line in the component. Is this possible? Am I missing a crucial concept of how Typescript/Angular works here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to return the observable from the service and subscribe to it in the component. This way, the async nature of the observable would be preserved and you'd get to invoke the presumed API call with different parameters if needed.

**Serivce**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

getNumberFromApi(): Observable<any> {
  return callAsync();
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someVar: any;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getNumberFromApi().subscribe({
      next: (value: any) => this.someVar = value,
      error: (error: any) => { }
    });
  }
}
```

On the other hand, if the variable `someVar` in the component is only used in the template to render some data, you could skip the subscription in the component controller and use the Angular [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someVar$: Observable<any>;   // <-- dollar sign is only a convention

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.someVar$ = this.someService.getNumberFromApi();
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(someVar$ | async) as someVar">
  <!-- use `someVar` -->
  {{ someVar }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Argh, please don't "staticize" the variable in this way. Use the `async` pipe on the final Observable to show its contents in the template. This sort of thing is considered strong code smell.

Comment: @WillAlexander: I'm updating the answer as you post this comment.

Comment: Thanks :) I also strongly suggest not using subscribe callbacks. Pipeable operators are 99% of the time your best option.

Comment: @WillAlexander: I've been intrigued by this recent trend against subscribe callbacks. Is there any reason for it other than aesthetically pleasing?

Comment: Thanks. So the assignment can never be done on the service's side, as I  suspected. There is no mechanism for that. In my real scenario, 'result' is actually a complex form called  form:FormGroup  .. I would like to pass the  form to a service method, let the service make all the necessary modifications without having to return the form at the end and re-assign it in the component .. But I guess it's not possible then.

Comment: You can add the `map` operator to the service's Observable which makes all the changes you want, and the final FormGroup will be emitted and received by the component. The whole point of the `async` pipe is you never "reassign" anything: the component simply reacts to the latest emission from the Observable.

Comment: @ruth subscribe callbacks almost always do "too much", and modifying behaviour becomes an arduous process. A well-written pipe, where operators do what they're supposed to do, is far easier to read (not just "aesthetically pleasing ^^) and reason with, and any time you want to modify an implementation, you know exactly where to do it.

Comment: @ruth it's a sort of "Observable hygiene", a bit like washing your hands. It helps you to think in a "cleaner code" way. I teach subscribe callbacks as being code smell :) OAAB — operators are always better!

Comment: @ruth this.someVar$ = this.someService.getNumberFromApi(); this is relative simple, but in my case I would like to pass $someVar -a complex object (FormGroup) with nested values- to the getNumberFromApi()  method (forget that name now), let the method on the service side make internal modifications to the object, and then return the modified object to the component. In such a case should I find a way to return the form as an observable from the service so that I can keep it constantly updated like in your second example?

Comment: @WillAlexander: Thanks for the explanation. I understand your PoV, but wouldn't it mean to perform side-effects using the `tap` operator instead of the subscription callbacks? Isn't performing side-effects using `tap` frowned upon by some?

Comment: @imnotthatrobot: Yes, when you depend on a response from an observable, the whole paradigm that depends on it (like your `FormGroup`) becomes asynchronous. If you so wish to send an object to the service, and send the modified object back, it'd need to be an observable. You'd need to [create an observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) in the service function, subscribe to the API call, push the response through the observable, and make sure to complete it. If all this sounds complicated, it is. What you're asking for is much simply achievable by returning the API call and using `async`.

Comment: @ruth: `tap` is for side effects. The docs say: "Used to perform side-effects for notifications from the source observable"

Comment: @WillAlexander: I agree. Though I've heard from others in similar vain that `tap` may be used for side-effects like `console.log` and may not trigger other functions. I fail to find the link to those comments now. Will post later if I ever wind up finding them.